# Parsing cmd args like typical filter programs

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I spent few hours reading tutorials about argparse and managed to learn to use normal parameters. The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) is not very readable to me. I'm new to Python. I'm trying to write a program that could be invoked in following ways:

`cat inFile | program [options] > outFile` -- If no inFile or outfile is specified, read from stdin and output to stdout.

`program [options] inFile outFile`

`program [options] inFile > outFile` -- If only one file is specified it is input and output should go to stdout.

`cat inFile | program [options] - outFile` -- If '-' is given in place of inFlie read from stdin.

`program [options] /path/to/folder outFile` -- Process all files from `/path/to/folder` and it subdirectories.

I want it to behave like regular cli program under GNU/Linux.

It would be also nice if the program would be able to be invoked:

`program [options] inFile0 inFile1 ... inFileN outFile` -- first path/file always interpreted as input, last one always interpreted as output. Any additional ones interpreted as inputs.

I could probably write dirty code that would accomplish this but this is going to be used, so someone will end up maintaining it (and he will know where I live...).

Any help/suggestions are much appreciated.

---

Combining answers and some more knowledge from the Internet I've managed to write this(it does not accept multiple inputs but this is enough):

```
import sys, argparse, os.path, glob

def inputFile(path):
    if path == "-":
        return [sys.stdin]
    elif os.path.exists(path):
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            return [path]
        else:
            return [y for x in os.walk(path) for y in glob.glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.dat'))]
    else:
        exit(2)

def main(argv):
    cmdArgsParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    cmdArgsParser.add_argument('inFile', nargs='?', default='-', type=inputFile)
    cmdArgsParser.add_argument('outFile', nargs='?', default='-', type=argparse.FileType('w'))
    cmdArgs = cmdArgsParser.parse_args()

    print cmdArgs.inFile
    print cmdArgs.outFile

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is a `howto` tutorial mentioned at the the start of the module docs.  `argparse.FileType` is capable of handling stdin/out (as '-'); but it opens both input and output files.  Would you prefer to open and close the files yourself?

Comment: @hpaulj: I've read the howto. I need to also work on directories, so that probably means I will have to return a list of file paths to iterate over later.

Comment: I added notes to my answer; I think most of script belongs after argparse, not within it.  Use argparse to get the strings.  Use your own code change dirs and open files.

Comment: This is not how most CLI programs are designed.  Some have an `-o destinationfile` to specify the output file, but the common design is for the non-option arguments to be input file names (or in peculiar cases directory names).  Usually, the shell handles I/O redirection and directory recursion with all the frills you would ever want quite nicely, with adequate control over corner cases which would otherwise complicate your program a lot (recurse directories or just examine files immediately within the directory?  Overwrite or append output file?)

Comment: @tripleee: As far as I know the only nonstandard thing about this is finding files in path recursively if path to directory is given. I am supposed to write a program that processes whole directories of files under Windows. Since I don't fancy M$. I am trying to write the program so that it would be cross platform and  similar to GNU/Linux CLI. I'm not familiar with Windows CLI. And behavior I described seems very intuitive to me after many years of using GNU/Linux. You are right about it complicating code. But I don't think it will complicate code a lot.

Comment: Just pointing out the obvious -- typical filter programs accept a list of input files (or read stdin if there are none), and write to standard output.  Part of the expectation for a properly written CLI tool is that it will run in batch over many files if you need it.  IMHO, tools which expect the output file name as the second file name argument generally feel windows-y / newbie-y.

Answer (score 2):

You need a positional argument (name not starting with a dash), optional arguments (`nargs='?'`), a default argument (`default='-'`). Additionally, `argparse.FileType` is a convenience factory to return `sys.stdin` or `sys.stdout` if `-` is passed (depending on the mode).

All together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse

# default argument is sys.argv[0]
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('foo')
parser.add_argument('in_file', nargs='?', default='-', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('out_file', nargs='?', default='-', type=argparse.FileType('w'))

def main():
    # default argument is is sys.argv[1:]
    args = parser.parse_args(['bar', 'baz'])
    print(args)
    args = parser.parse_args(['bar', '-'])
    print(args)
    args = parser.parse_args(['bar'])
    print(args)
    args = parser.parse_args(['-', 'baz'])
    print(args)
    args = parser.parse_args(['-', '-'])
    print(args)
    args = parser.parse_args(['-'])
    print(args)
    args = parser.parse_args([])
    print(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It works nice except it can't open directories. I imagine that I should call some function. In argparse docs I found that "type=func()" will call a function (as You just did). I have written a simple function that uses os.path to check if the argument is a directory or a file. I just don't know how to pass the path to it or how to return some structure/type/? that will allow for later processing (I want to iterate over all files in the directory recursively).

Comment: I've figured out how to pass argument to the function. Now I just need to return some list of files to process or something along those lines. Thx o11c!

Comment: @lynx If you want to pass multiple input arguments on the command-line (in which case you can't have an output argument), you would use `nargs='*'`

Comment: I have to have `program inFile outFile` scenario working. more input files would be nice but is optional. I find it strange that the library would not allow for such use.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a start script to play with.  It uses `optionals` rather than `positionals`. and only one input file.  But it should give a taste of what you can do.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
inarg = parser.add_argument('-i','--infile', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default='-')
outarg = parser.add_argument('-o','--outfile', type=argparse.FileType('w'), default='-')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)
cnt = 0
for line in args.infile:
    print(cnt, line)
    args.outfile.write(line)
    cnt += 1
```

When called without arguments, it just echos your input (after ^D).  I'm a little bothered that it doesn't exit until I issue another ^D.

`FileType` is convenient, but has the major fault - it opens the files, but you have to close them yourself, or let Python do so when exiting.  There's also the complication that you don't want to close stdin/out.

The best `argparse` questions include a basic script, and specific questions on how to correct or improve it.  Your specs are reasonably clear. but it would be nice if you gave us more to work with.

---

To handle the subdirectories option, I would skip the `FileType` bit.  Use `argparse` to get 2 lists of strings (or a list and an name), and then do the necessary `chgdir` and or `glob` to find and iterate over files.  Don't expect `argparse` to do the actual work.  Use it to parse the commandline strings.  Here a sketch of such a script, leaving most details for you to fill in.

```
import argparse
import os
import sys # of stdin/out
....
def open_output(outfile):
   # function to open a file for writing
   # should handle '-'
   # return a file object

def glob_dir(adir):
    # function to glob a dir
    # return a list of files ready to open

def open_forread(afilename):
    # function to open file for reading
    # be sensitive to '-'

def walkdirs(alist):
    outlist = []
    for name in alist:
        if <name is file>;
            outlist.append(name)
        else <name is a dir>:
            glist = glob(dir)
            outlist.extend(glist)
        else:
            <error>
    return outlist

def cat(infile, outfile):
    <do your thing here>

def main(args):
    # handle args options
    filelist = walkdirs(args.inlist)
    fout = open_outdir(args.outfile)
    for name in filelist:
        fin = open_forread(name)
        cat(fin,fout)
        if <fin not stdin>: fin.close()
    if <fout not stdout>: fout.close()

if '__name__' == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('inlist', nargs='*')
    parser.add_argument('outfile')
    # add options 
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

The `parser` here requires you to give it an `outfile` name, even if it is '-'.   I could define its `nargs='?'` to make it optional.  But that does not play nicely with the 'inlist` '*'.

Consider

```
myprog one two three
```

Is that

```
namespace(inlist=['one','two','three'], outfile=default)
```

or

```
namespace(inlist=['one','two'], outfile='three')
```

With both a `*` and `?` positional, the identity of the last string is ambiguous - is it the last entry for `inlist`, or the optional entry for `outfile`?  `argparse` chooses the former, and never assigns the value to `outfile`.

With `--infile`, `--outfile` definitions, the allocation of these strings is clear.

In sense this problem is too complex for `argparse` - there's nothing in it to handle things like directories.  In another sense it is too simple.  You could just as easily split `sys.argv[1:]` between `inlist` and `outfile` without the help of `argparse`.